# Dual linear map

Tags: dual-spaces, dual-maps

Is it possible to determine the dual linear map base independently?
Say $V = P_3(x)$ is the vector space of polynomials up to grade 3 and $W = P_2(x)$.
Be $T: V \to W$, $p \mapsto p'$,
what is the corresponding dual map $T^*: W^* \to V^*$?

Comment: Let $f \in W^*$, then $(T^*f) \in V^*$ is defined as $(T^*f)(v):= f(Tv)$. Now try this definition in your example.

Comment: Thank you. I did exactly this. But how to "solve" for T* ?